# Microsoft Graph: Get access without a user

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I have successfully implement the "OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow" to access my outlook.com calendar. Now I would like to implement the "OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow". When accessing

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?...

I get the following error:

GET /OAuthTest0?error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS50020%3a+...

Do I need an Office356 and/or an Azure Active Directory license to implement the "client credentials flow"?

Thanks

Emil

Comment: Please include your detail error message . And also are you using azure ad v2.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the Client Credentials flow with personal/consumer Microsoft Accounts (XBox, Outlook.com, etc.). This OAUTH flow is only applicable to Work/School (aka Azure AD) accounts.